# Does windows 7 automatically restart the WSEARCH service after I stopped it?

Tags: windows, windows-7

I am trying to stop the Windows Search (WSEARCH) service, I type NET STOP WSEARCH, and within 3 minutes, it is running again. How can I find out who is restarting it, and stop them? Do I need to disable the service?

Comment: I agree to Rodrigo's answer. My question is, however: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: If you need to re-enable it in the future be sure to set it to Enabled (Delayed Start), which is the default setting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try "sc config "wsearch" start= disabled" or use the graphical "services.msc" to mark it as disabled.

Note: A space is required after start= or it won't be accepted.

Comment: You're going to have to disable the service, or it's going to automatically restart. It's like the Indexing service of XP.

Comment: note that a space is required after start= or sc won't accept it.

Answer (score 1):

To stop it and have it stay stopped, I used this:

```
net stop wsearch
sc config "wsearch" start= disabled
```

To restart it I used this:

```
sc config "wsearch" start= auto
net start wsearch
```

Note that the space after the start= parameter is required (thanks to a lazy programmer at Microsoft who didn't want to write a thorough command line parsing function).