# what restarts the wsearch service after I stop it?

Tags: windows, search, services

As answered in [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/236253/does-windows-7-automatically-restart-the-wsearch-service-after-i-stopped-it), Windows (7, and now 10) *does* restart the `wsearch` service after someone deliberately stops it. As that question also explains, one can disable the service to prevent it from starting.

My question: When the `StartState`, or `StartupState`, is `Manual` and the `Status` is `Stopped`, what part of Windows is it, exactly, that is restarting the `wsearch` service. I could not find a task in the Task Scheduler that appeared to do it.

(I understand that when the `StartState`, or `StartupState`, is `Disabled` the service will not start.)

To clarity [The above question](https://superuser.com/questions/236253/does-windows-7-automatically-restart-the-wsearch-service-after-i-stopped-it) asks "who is restarting it" but it seems evident their only purpose was stop it from restarting. They were not interested the somewhat academic question of *what part* of Windows is re-starting the service. I'm looking for a deeper understanding of how it gets restarted in the first place.

Here are some relevant entries from the event log:

```
==================================================
Event Time        : 7/31/2021 12:16:38 PM.042
Event ID          : 1003
Description       : The Windows Search Service started.
==================================================
Event Time        : 7/31/2021 12:16:37 PM.826
Event ID          : 102
Description       : SearchIndexer (1584,P,98) Windows: The database engine (10.00.19042.0000) is starting a new instance (0).
==================================================
Event Time        : 7/31/2021 12:16:37 PM.809
Event ID          : 2
Description       : Process '\Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\System32\SearchIndexer.exe' (PID 1584) was blocked from generating dynamic code.
[that pid is the new SearchIndexer.exe process housing the Windows Search service,
 having already been restarted by now.]
==================================================
[these entries are adjacent in the event log]
==================================================
Event Time        : 7/31/2021 12:16:20 PM.536
Event ID          : 1013
Description       : Windows Search Service stopped normally.
==================================================
Event Time        : 7/31/2021 12:16:20 PM.520
Event ID          : 103
Description       : SearchIndexer (9324,T,97) Windows: The database engine stopped the instance (0). 
==================================================
```

So the event log does not appear to say who started it, nor even have an entry that records its start.

So does that mean that the "operating system" is restarting it?

Anybody know which part?

**EDIT:** question was closed as a duplicate of [the question I referred to above](https://superuser.com/questions/236253/does-windows-7-automatically-restart-the-wsearch-service-after-i-stopped-it), however while that question does ask "who" is restarting `wsearch`, it does not ask **which part of Windows** specifically, and anyway, it is not answered there, and their true *goal*--preventing it from starting--was answered. This question here is intended to go deeper. Thanks!

**EDIT 2:** the question was re-opened. Thanks!

Comment: Open the Services app, find the "Windows Search" service and double-click it. What do you have next to "Startup type" and "Service status"?

Comment: If it says "Manual" and "Stopped" something restarts it. If it says "Disabled" and "Stopped" nothing restarts it. My question is what is restarting it when it's in "Manual" and "Stopped". I'll edit the question to be clearer

Comment: The question was closed as a duplicate but that question does not ask, or answer, WHAT PART OF WINDOWS TRIGGERS THE RESTART of the service. Thanks.